# Google Plus comments as a feed

Tags: google-plus

I run a blog and use Google Plus as a promotion tool, posting on G+ every updates. As I have hundreds of followers, quite often my G+ posts have several comments: I would like to show them on my blog!

I know there are a few tools that give you back the latest xxx post given the G+ User ID, but what about the feed about a single G+ post?

Thank you.
Francesco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch that data using the documentation here: http://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/get